# Context menu ICommand doesn't fire in my mvvm windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8, contextmenu

I have the following the contextmenu defined in the view.

```
     <ListBox x:Name="lstSavedTracks"   ItemsSource="{Binding SavedMusicTracksDataSource}"          Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0"  >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate >

                                <StackPanel >
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="view" CommandParameter="{Binding}"   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlayTrackCommand}"/>
                                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="delete" CommandParameter="{Binding}"  Command="{Binding Path=DeleteTrackCommand}"/>
                                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>

                                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="20"  Text="{Binding TrackTitle}"  TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                                    <Line MinHeight="5"></Line>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>

                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

I have the below ViewModel set as datacontext for the above view.the ICommand  works for the controls such as buttons when I am using commands binding for click events. But it doesn't work for my contextmenu commands.

```
  public System.Windows.Input.ICommand ViewTrackCommand
    {
        get
        {

            return new DelegateCommand((o) =>
            {

                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    PlayTrack();
                });
            });
        }
   }


 public System.Windows.Input.ICommand DeleteTrackCommand
    {
        get
        {

            return new DelegateCommand((o) =>
            {

                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    DeleteTrack();
                });
            });
        }
   }
```

I tried the similar icommand binding for the buttons click event and they work fine..but it doesn't work the context menu. Is there anything that I am missing here?

FYI: Icommand implementation which is working for buttons..

```
public class DelegateCommand : System.Windows.Input.ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }


    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}//end of class
```

Comment: Did you check out the provided sample on codeplex? They work with ICommand as well, but don't use the "Path" attribute while binding the Command. Simply: Command="{Binding DeleteTrackCommand}"
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Release/WindowsPhone71/PhoneToolkitSample/Samples/ContextMenuSample.xaml

Comment: I have checked it but I don't want to use the code behind..this is the only place where I am not able to apply mvvm..

Answer (score 0):

You need point out clear Path and Source of ViewModel like this:

Command="{Binding TestVM.DeleteTrackCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"

Hope this help you.